# process files in a list according to a pre-defined order

Tags: r

I want to process my files according to a particular order. For instance, there is an ID in the file names and I want to process them with following order:

```
order <- c("5521","6572","9882","6583")
```

files:

```
6572.txt
5521.bww.txt
6583.rrrwe.txt
9882.tw.txt



files <- list.files()
filelist <- lapply(files, function)
names(filelist) <- paste0(basename((files)))
```

Then I want process according to "order" BUT still loop through all files

I tried for loop and grep but I do not think it is good idea:

```
for(i in 1:length(names(filelist))) {

  grep(order[i]..)

  (FUNCTION)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort your file list according to the `order` vector. In your example, the `order` vector contains basename without extension. You need to format your file list similarly.

```
files <- list.files()
file_no_ext <- sub("^([^.]*).*", "\\1", files))
```

Then get indices where elements in `file_no_ext` *matches* `order`. Use these indices to reorder the original `files` list.

```
files <- files[ match(order,file_no_ext) ]
lapply(files, yourFun)
```

Hope this help. Let me know if not.

**EDIT**
Instead of removing file extension, you can do a a partial string matching using `pmatch`

```
files <- files[ pmatch(order, files) ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is very helpful. in the case that my file names are more complex, is it possible to do a partial pattern match based on "order"?

Comment: That would be great. I meant without file_no_ext.

Comment: Thanks ahmohamed. I can not find pmatch. it is not available anymore! :(

Comment: I'm running R 3.1, and it is there. I can't find any source that indicates it was removed. have a look [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pmatch.html) and maybe you can try [charmatch](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/charmatch.html)

Comment: I just installed a couple of old R packages and it is really fuuny!! none of them available (for R version 3.1.0)